# Python: for a given edge, create a circle, which radius is this edge

Tags: python

I'm working on an add-on to automate the generation of a specific 3D model.
I have to add circles which centers must be at the ends of selected edges.
The radius of each circle must be the length of the relevant edge (see pictures at the end).

I've created a dictionary with information on the edges but now i have to filter it to obtain only the center and the radius in my dictionary.

Example of the dictionary when 2 edges are selected :

```
Edge:446 Point: 443 / x:-67.67 / y:58.39 /z:0.0 / d:89.38  
Edge:446 Point: 437 / x:-53.61 / y:46.26 /z:0.0 / d:70.81  
Edge:447 Point: 444 / x:-66.07 / y:59.97 /z:0.0 / d:89.23  
Edge:447 Point: 438 / x:-52.25 / y:47.43 /z:0.0 / d:70.57
```

The Edge 446 is made with points 443 and 437. The `d` is the distance between the origin and the point.
I just want to keep the point for which `d` is the greatest. And I want to add the difference between distances of the two points (the radius for the circle).

```
Edge:446 Point: 443 / x:-67.67 / y:58.39 /z:0.0 / d:89.38 / r:18.57  
Edge:447 Point: 438 / x:-52.25 / y:47.43 /z:0.0 / d:70.57 / r:18.66
```

---

```
    def execute(self, context):

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    scene = bpy.context.scene

    obj = bpy.context.object
   
    dic_v = {}
  
    for o in bpy.context.objects_in_mode:
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(o.data)
        print(bm)
        for v in bm.edges:
            if v.select:
               for p in v.verts :
                   d = math.sqrt(p.co[0] **2 + p.co[1]**2)
                   print(f"Edge:{v.index} Point:{p.index} / x:{p.co[0]} / y:{p.co[1]} /z:{p.co[2]} d:{d}")
                   Segment = {(p.index) : (p.co[0],p.co[1],d)}
                   dic_v.update(Segment)
```

[image: The edges where the circles must be]

[image: The circles in place]

Comment: This seems to be more about Python techniques than about Blender: Python dictionaries work the same way in external Python. Am I wrong, here?

Comment: Isn't the end of an edge the point farthest from the origin? Isn't it, the point with the highest d value?

Comment: Thanks Rivin. Yes you 're right. But when i said origin i would like to say the origine of the selected object. So in this case it's equal to d value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is not about the dictionary at all...

Spawning a circle on an edge, where the edge becomes a radius of the circle:

```py
import bpy, bmesh
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import Matrix

ob = C.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

for edge in bm.select_history:
    if type(edge) is not bmesh.types.BMEdge:
        continue  # not actually an edge...
    vert = edge.verts[0]
    delta = (vert.co - edge.verts[1].co)
    r = delta.length
    Q = delta.to_track_quat('X', 'Y')
    M = Matrix.LocRotScale(vert.co, Q, (1, 1, 1))
    geom = bmesh.ops.create_circle(bm, segments=20, radius=r, matrix=M)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

[image]

Notice how the circles are not always aligned, because there's another problem - figuring out which vertex to choose as the center of each circle... You need to somehow traverse the mesh and figure out an algorithm deciding which vertex to pick, e.g. the closest vertex to the center of the previous circle...

Comment: Thanks a lot Markus. That's exactely what i want. I'm beginner in Python so i will analyse your answer especially the problem.

Comment: Markus. I take time but i think i've all understand. That's perfect for my case. The index of the vertex in an edge depend of this order of creation. The first created vertex take the index 0 and the other index 1. All the vertices which are used to be the circles centers are created before others vertices. So index of centers are all 0. Thanks a lot for your help.